# Ruby app deployed on and amazon linux instance: Create an object from assets folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services

In development and on a localhost I do the following in order to get the image from the assets folder and then create a new attachment:

```
Attachment.create(:image => File.open('app/assets/images/no-image.jpg', 'rb'), :item_id=> @item.id)
```

This works fine, but when in production and while the app is deployed on a `amazon linux instance` this doesn't work.

Also, I successfully executed the following command, but I still can't create the image:
`RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails assets:precompile`

All the other images I have inside the assets folder that are associated to page work just fine.

Any ideas what might be wrong

Comment: Try absolute path: `Rails.root.join('app/assets/images/no-image.jpg')`.

Comment: "this doesn't work" - what do you mean __exactly__?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Sergio Tulentsev , I meant that the above code doesn't create the object when I uploaded and deployed the app to the amazon instance I have created.

Comment: "I meant that the above code doesn't create the object" - yeah, I figured _that_. What I was hinting at (and maybe I should have been more direct) is: post any error messages that you get, in their entirety. About a thousand things can go wrong. How are we to know which one is it?

Comment: "doesn't create the object" - what does it do __instead__?

Comment: I can't tell from the logs, because its not showing me what went wrong... it's just giving me  `I, [2018-05-22T08:36:51.584498 #29340]  INFO -- : [1315c870-7e32-4753-886b-a7756800aaf3] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 30028ms (ActiveRecord: 4.7ms)`

Comment: I see. That's why you must always set up exception tracking/monitoring in production. I've tried sentry.io and honeybadger.io, but there are others too.